# VS 2012 Task list doesn't work in Typescript

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, tasklist

Is there a way to make the task list to work in Typescript projects?

It doesn't recognize any "TODO" comments. Only user tasks can be created.

**Update:**

I've raised a bug on the [Codeplex site](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/858).

Comment: Thanks, was wondering about this also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to raise a bug on the Codeplex site so the TypeScript team can allocate it to a developer and a release.

http://typescript.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Steve, I've raised a bug as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Update for the Codeplex bug opened by MichaelS:
Bug was moved to GitHub: [Task List tokens are not honored #1942](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1942) and was fixed only for Visual Studio 2015. Additionally, developers don't have plans to integrate this into any earlier VS version.

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the explanation you provide?

Comment: @Brian, actually my answer does summarize linked page. I don't see what else can be added here.